# SSH hang in Linux

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

I'm getting some weird behavior.  Hopefully I can fully explain the situation.  I'm using Alma Linux 8.

First, I have essential two systems hosted on separate VMWare ESXi hosts (we'll call them A and B), but all on the same network.  Each system has 4 VMs.  The primary VM (called "console") is accessed through VMWare Horizon client.

Console-A is working as expected.  The ssh command works with all its peers.  However, when logged in via Horizon, console-B cannot ssh into its peers.  It just hangs indefinitely (I left it running overnight, so it's indefinite). I'll call this the direct method.  Console-A can ssh into the B peers just fine.

Here's the weird part.  If I ssh into console-B from another machine, THEN I can ssh into its peers.  I'll call this the tunnel method.

I've compared the -vvv output for both scenarios and they are identical until the direct method just stops:

```
...
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from peer_machine
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from {ip address masked}
debug1: Host 'left' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
```

The tunnel method continues with:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:3+{data masked}
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/username/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
...
```

I've tried the following:

1. Removing the .ssh directory on console
2. Removing the .ssh directory on peer
3. dnf reinstall openssh-clients
4. dnf update
5. Cloning console-A to console-B

Thoughts?

Comment: What's the state of SSH agent? Can you compare environments on the weirdly behaving box in case "direct" method and "tunnel" method? Most interesting are variables that begin with `SSH_`, but some others may be also of interest.

Comment: I agree it's probably the agent. Run `ssh` through `strace` to see what the last operation is: `strace ssh ...`